# can not import technical library - freqtrade

Tags: python, trading, algorithmic-trading, technical-indicator

it seems to be a problem on where python is searching for de library and not finding it.
still, im very new in this so may be its another thing.

this is the error (i separated the middle part where i think shows the problem):

ftuser@a5a1d3ed08d3:/freqtrade$ freqtrade backtesting --strategy canal
2022-08-26 03:51:37,394 - freqtrade.configuration.load_config - INFO - Using config: user_data/config.json ...
2022-08-26 03:51:37,483 - freqtrade.loggers - INFO - Verbosity set to 0
2022-08-26 03:51:37,484 - freqtrade.configuration.configuration - INFO - Using max_open_trades: 1 ...
2022-08-26 03:51:37,716 - freqtrade.configuration.configuration - INFO - Using user-data directory: /freqtrade/user_data ...
2022-08-26 03:51:37,718 - freqtrade.configuration.configuration - INFO - Using data directory: /freqtrade/user_data/data/binance ...
2022-08-26 03:51:37,719 - freqtrade.configuration.configuration - INFO - Parameter --cache=day detected ...
2022-08-26 03:51:37,719 - freqtrade.configuration.check_exchange - INFO - Checking exchange...
2022-08-26 03:51:37,741 - freqtrade.configuration.check_exchange - INFO - Exchange "binance" is officially supported by the Freqtrade development team.
2022-08-26 03:51:37,741 - freqtrade.configuration.configuration - INFO - Using pairlist from configuration.
2022-08-26 03:51:37,741 - freqtrade.configuration.config_validation - INFO - Validating configuration ...
2022-08-26 03:51:37,746 - freqtrade.commands.optimize_commands - INFO - Starting freqtrade in Backtesting mode
2022-08-26 03:51:37,746 - freqtrade.exchange.exchange - INFO - Instance is running with dry_run enabled
2022-08-26 03:51:37,746 - freqtrade.exchange.exchange - INFO - Using CCXT 1.92.20
2022-08-26 03:51:37,746 - freqtrade.exchange.exchange - INFO - Applying additional ccxt config: {'options': {'defaultType': 'future'}}
2022-08-26 03:51:37,766 - freqtrade.exchange.exchange - INFO - Applying additional ccxt config: {'options': {'defaultType': 'future'}}
2022-08-26 03:51:37,782 - freqtrade.exchange.exchange - INFO - Using Exchange "Binance"
2022-08-26 03:51:39,052 - freqtrade.resolvers.exchange_resolver - INFO - Using resolved exchange 'Binance'...

2022-08-26 03:51:39,097 - freqtrade.resolvers.iresolver - WARNING - Could not import /freqtrade/user_data/strategies/canal.py due to 'cannot import name 'SSLchannels' from 'technical.indicators' (/home/ftuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/technical/indicators/**init**.py)'

2022-08-26 03:51:39,182 - freqtrade - ERROR - Impossible to load Strategy 'canal'. This class does not exist or contains Python code errors.
2022-08-26 03:51:39,182 - freqtrade.exchange.exchange - INFO - Closing async ccxt session.

this is the code in VS Code:

```
import numpy as np  # noqa
import pandas as pd  # noqa
from pandas import DataFrame


from freqtrade.strategy import (BooleanParameter, CategoricalParameter, DecimalParameter,
                                IStrategy, IntParameter)

# --------------------------------
# Add your lib to import here
import talib.abstract as ta
import freqtrade.vendor.qtpylib.indicators as qtpylib
from technical.indicators import SSLchannels


# This class is a sample. Feel free to customize it.
class canal(IStrategy):
    

    INTERFACE_VERSION = 3

    # Can this strategy go short?
    can_short: bool = False

    # Minimal ROI designed for the strategy.
    # This attribute will be overridden if the config file contains "minimal_roi".
    minimal_roi = {
        "60": 0.01,
        "30": 0.02,
        "0": 0.04
    }

    # Optimal stoploss designed for the strategy.
    # This attribute will be overridden if the config file contains "stoploss".
    stoploss = -0.10

    # Trailing stoploss
    trailing_stop = False
    # trailing_only_offset_is_reached = False
    # trailing_stop_positive = 0.01
    # trailing_stop_positive_offset = 0.0  # Disabled / not configured

    # Optimal timeframe for the strategy.
    timeframe = '5m'

    # Run "populate_indicators()" only for new candle.
    process_only_new_candles = True

    # These values can be overridden in the config.
    use_exit_signal = True
    exit_profit_only = False
    ignore_roi_if_entry_signal = False

    buy_rsi = IntParameter(low=1, high=50, default=30, space='buy', optimize=True, load=True)
    sell_rsi = IntParameter(low=50, high=100, default=70, space='sell', optimize=True, load=True)
    short_rsi = IntParameter(low=51, high=100, default=70, space='sell', optimize=True, load=True)
    exit_short_rsi = IntParameter(low=1, high=50, default=30, space='buy', optimize=True, load=True)


    # Number of candles the strategy requires before producing valid signals
    startup_candle_count: int = 30

    # Optional order type mapping.
    order_types = {
        'entry': 'limit',
        'exit': 'limit',
        'stoploss': 'market',
        'stoploss_on_exchange': False
    }

    # Optional order time in force.
    order_time_in_force = {
        'entry': 'gtc',
        'exit': 'gtc'
    }

    plot_config = {
        'main_plot': {
            'tema': {},
            'sar': {'color': 'white'},
        },
        'subplots': {
            "MACD": {
                'macd': {'color': 'blue'},
                'macdsignal': {'color': 'orange'},
            },
            "RSI": {
                'rsi': {'color': 'red'},
            }
        }
    }

    def informative_pairs(self):
        """
        Define additional, informative pair/interval combinations to be cached from the exchange.
        These pair/interval combinations are non-tradeable, unless they are part
        of the whitelist as well.
        For more information, please consult the documentation
        :return: List of tuples in the format (pair, interval)
            Sample: return [("ETH/USDT", "5m"),
                            ("BTC/USDT", "15m"),
                            ]
        """
        return []

    def populate_indicators(self, dataframe: DataFrame, metadata: dict) -> DataFrame:


        # RSI
        dataframe['rsi'] = ta.RSI(dataframe)
    
        return dataframe

    def populate_entry_trend(self, dataframe: DataFrame, metadata: dict) -> DataFrame:

        
        dataframe.loc[
            (
                # Signal: RSI crosses above 30
                (qtpylib.crossed_above(dataframe['rsi'], self.buy_rsi.value)) &
                
                (dataframe['volume'] > 0)  # Make sure Volume is not 0
            ),
            'enter_long'] = 1

        dataframe.loc[
            (
                # Signal: RSI crosses above 70
                (qtpylib.crossed_above(dataframe['rsi'], self.short_rsi.value)) &
            
                (dataframe['volume'] > 0)  # Make sure Volume is not 0
            ),
            'enter_short'] = 1

        return dataframe
        

    def populate_exit_trend(self, dataframe: DataFrame, metadata: dict) -> DataFrame:
    
        dataframe.loc[
            (
                # Signal: RSI crosses above 70
                (qtpylib.crossed_above(dataframe['rsi'], self.sell_rsi.value)) &
            
                (dataframe['volume'] > 0)  # Make sure Volume is not 0
            ),

            'exit_long'] = 1

        dataframe.loc[
            (
                # Signal: RSI crosses above 30
                (qtpylib.crossed_above(dataframe['rsi'], self.exit_short_rsi.value)) &
                # Guard: tema below BB middle
                
                (dataframe['volume'] > 0)  # Make sure Volume is not 0
            ),
            'exit_short'] = 1

        return dataframe
```

I left RSI indicator so that i could coment:

#from technical.indicators import SSLchannels

and test the code is ok and it works. It runs the backtest ok.

- Heres how i have the folders in my PC

[image]

[image]

I also tryed choosing python 3.8 and 3.10 in VS Code just ro try and both work well if i take out technical library and shows error if i put it.

any help would be apreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that the `freqtrade` is not loading? I guess it is loading perfectly. Anyways, the source code of the 3rd party modules is kept in the `lib` folder of the environment. I have not used this specific module. My comment is based on the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that either you need to pip install the technical.indicators or use docker. I prefer using docker to execute freqtrade commands as they already have all the dependencies installed.

Comment: Thanks all. I resolved to take another way to reaching mi goal withowt using the "technical" library.